# Raphael JS resize Canvas

Tags: graph, canvas, resize, dynamic, raphael

I'm programming a debate-graph with Raphael JS. Users can add nodes to the graph. Eventually the graph gets really big and the canvas is still the same size. the canvas (in raphael js: paper) is inside another div with "overflow: scroll;", so lets ignore screen real estate

Is there a way that I resize the canvas without reloading the page (to assign new X/Y values)?
Alternatively, can I create a second bigger canvas in parallel and copying all the elements over? is there a way?

Answer (score 17):

If I understand your question, just call [setSize()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setSize) to expand the size of the canvas to the size needed as you need it. I've used this in a div with overflow:scroll to get the effect you describe.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I didn't want to resize, I wanted to zoom.

In other words, show the user the growing graph inside a constant-sized div.

So I needed: [setViewBox()](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.setViewBox)